# JSDOM function does not finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js, jsdom

Please help me understand what is wrong here:

Here is my js code (simplified to isolate the minimal code required to demonstrate the problem):

```
'use strict';
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
describe('desc', function () {
    it('should', function () {
        function uploadURL(callback) {
            jsdom.env({
                url: "http://digg.com",
                done: function (errors, window) {
                    console.log("inside");
                    callback("abc");
                }
            });
        }

        uploadURL(function(x){
            console.log("returned " + x);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my command line:

> node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/test.js

When I run the above script, I'm getting the following output:

```
  desc
    ✓ should (196ms)
  1 passing (204ms)
```

Once I remove the jsdom part and run only the part of the uploadURL() that contains console.log and callback, I get this back:

```
desc
inside
returned abc
    ✓ should
  1 passing (5ms)
```

Seems like the jsdom part is not get executed before the script ends.
Why is this and how can this be worked out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's asynchronous. To test an asynchronous function with Mocha, you accept the callback Mocha's `it` provides, and call it when the async is done:

```
'use strict';
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
describe('desc', function () {
    it('should', function (done) {
    //                     ^---------------------- accept the callback
        function uploadURL(callback) {
            jsdom.env({
                url: "http://digg.com",
                done: function (errors, window) {
                    console.log("inside");
                    callback("abc");
                }
            });
        }

        uploadURL(function(x){
            console.log("returned " + x);
            done();                            // <=== Call it
        });
    });
});
```

This is covered in the Mocha documentation [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I am getting the following error when trying your suggestion: Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Comment: @Katya: Sounds like it's taking more than 2 seconds to query digg.com and parse the result. I expect there's a configuration parameter somewhere that lets you extend the timeout.

Comment: Bingo! :) Adding the callback and setting "this.timeout(10000);" between 'describe' and 'it' solved the problem. Thanks a lot!